# They say "if you're banned from asking questions" then "fix your old questions", but what if my old questions are completely wrong and can't be fixed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, post-ban

I have asked some quick questions. Some of them are specific and I don't understand why they were downvoted, while others were too "quick-asked". By "quick-asked" I mean I could find the answer myself if I did some more research online.

But at the end they all are downvoted and most of them don't have any comments on why they are downvoted.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923908/how-do-i-compile-c-using-gcc-on-windows-8-1-64-bit): I don't understand why it's downvoted. It's a specific questions, I wrote what I did.

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921785/how-to-compile-a-simple-c-code-with-gcc-test-c-o-demo-command): I got 3 downvotes, because it was asked too quickly and could be answered easily by doing some more research online.

They say that I have to fix my questions, but to fix them, I have to edit them completely, make them into another question. I mean the questions are junk itself.

**How do I fix the questions if the questions are wrong itself?**

Comment: As for your questions, you can't gut them and ask something completely different; you've already got answers for them. You can't make edits that would invalidate the existing answers. You could try removing the find request from that second question (find/recommendation requests are off topic). But if you can't fix the bad ones, try improving the 0 score ones.

Comment: I have edited it. My question is not a duplicate. If I improve my 0 score ones, who'll see them and eventually upvote them? That's just a waste of time.

Comment: One really important thing to do is to make your **title specifically describe** the **particular hurdle** you're trying to overcome. See [the edit I just made](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33923908/revisions) to your first example. Titles that talk about big problems but are attached to questions about specific error messages make for bad search results and bad reading in the tag lists, and people will righfully downvote them as not useful.

Comment: What about this new title? It describes the particular hurdle.

Comment: The current title is incoherent: They "...". For starters, not being so sloppy and careless, and reading what you have written would go a long way to solve your problems.

Comment: Small grammatic errors, forgetting some words, misspellings etc. is very normal. But we get downvotes very fast. And when we fix these misspellings etc. they the downvotes won't go away. By the way it's not a website about English grammar.

Comment: It's not normal for people who *care*. "By the way it's not a website about English grammar." -- Look; you're whining about getting downvotes. I'm giving you advice about how you can get fewer of them. Take it or not -- it's your choice. "they (sic) the downvotes won't go away" -- Not unless the people who downvoted go back and look and change their minds. Since that isn't likely to happen, get it right in the first place *if you don't want to be downvoted*.

Comment: *who'll see them and eventually upvote them?* The same people who would see and up vote improvements to the questions with negative scores, namely, folks who look at questions with recent activity. Edits put your question back at the top of that list. I don't know why you're asking how to fix your questions if you think it's a waste of time.

Comment: There is another way to get out from under the burden of negatively scored questions.  Your questions are well formed and well asked, but poorly researched.  Asking trivial questions just wastes people's time.  You need to break yourself of that habit.  So, here's a chance to do so.  With some good research, you can find out how you can release yourself from these poor questions by searching and reading over on [meta.se].  If you figure it out, make sure you say that you realize your mistake (poor research) and *will be much better in future*.  Good luck on your hunt!

Answer (score 15):

There *are* actually other ways of getting out of a post ban.

You could try answering some questions. You haven't done *any* of that yet; spending some time trying to understand other people's problems is a pretty great way of learning how to formulate your own properly.

You could also try your hand at editing. Lotta people asking questions that are just plain *hard to read*, with lousy explanations and terrible titles. Help 'em out. In the process, learn how to help yourself...

It'll probably take you a long, long time to work your way out of a ban by answering or editing. There was one guy I watched who spent months - the better part of a year - doing it. Of course, he was pretty ill at the time too, so you might have an easier time of it. Then again, he might've been more motivated.

Of course, you might learn a few things along the way that enable you to make some improvements to your existing questions that'll speed things up too. Never know...

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix the questions if the questions are wrong itself?

You don't.

You have asked questions that would be answered by doing basic research. Some of your questions are the equivalent of "how do I use my computer?" And what's worse... you *recognize* this fact, yet presumably you asked them anyway.

If your questions are of a nature where they cannot be made better... then we're done with you. You had your chance. *Eleven separate chances.* Stack Overflow has tolerated your behavior, but that tolerance has reached its end.

This may seem harsh, but at the end of the day, it was you who repeatedly violated the standards of our community.

Good day, sir.

Oh, BTW:

> Even here, Nicol Bolas and Jim Balter upvotes each other's comments and answers. So here's "you scratch my back and i'll scratch yours" mentality.

[image: Objection!]

That's my screenshot; no upvotes on comments from me.

Conspiracy theory disproven.

Comment: No, none of my questions is equivalent of "how do I use my computer". I have used a lot of similar platforms online. Yes my questions are nooby, but they are specific enough. There are just a lot of "down voters" who just down-vote almost everything they see online. And there are a group of users who upvote each other's posts. A bit like "you scratch my back and i'll scratch yours" mentality.

Comment: @Coder88: "*No, none of my questions is equivalent of "how do I use my computer".*" The very first question you asked showed that you didn't know how to run an application from the command line. Putting programs in your command line is pretty basic stuff for anyone trying to do anything with the command line. Like programmers.

Comment: Command line is not something most computer-user uses these days.

Comment: "There are just a lot of "down voters" who just down-vote almost everything they see online. And there are a group of users who upvote each other's posts. A bit like "you scratch my back and i'll scratch yours" mentality" -- You cannot validate any of these claims. And suppose they were really true ... then this isn't the sort of place you want to be at. Ta ta.

Comment: Even here, Nicol Bolas and Jim Balter upvotes each other's comments and answers. So here's "you scratch my back and i'll scratch yours" mentality.

Comment: Given the whole site is based around the idea of folks helping each other, I'm not quite seeing where metaphorical back-scratching is such an awful idea, @Coder88. "Pay it forward" would be a better one though. If someone's helped you out, find a way to help someone else and encourage them to do the same. Eventually, it all comes around.

Comment: *"Command line is not something most computer-user uses these days."* Well this site specifically targets programmers and not most computer-users ;)

Comment: I have 13 questions. Only 4 of them got downvotes, but with a total of 13 downvotes. 3 of them got upvotes, a total of 5 votes. But then I got permanently banned. It's normal to ban some users on this-like sites when they just destroy the site. But being banned permannetly just by 13 downvotes and net 8 downvotes, is just too strict. SO wants programmers to waste their time on working on SO and its rules.

Comment: So I've said some strict things about question quality, but this *really* crosses the line.  By the letter of the law you're probably right, but the spirit in which you express it really rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: 'There are just a lot of "down voters" who just down-vote almost everything they see online', yes, there are some of us.  I run out of downvotes quite often for that reason.  If almost everything I see online was not bad questions that deserve downvoting, that would not happen.

Comment: @Coder88 you mention the three upvoted questions and four downvoted, but note that the six with zero also count against you; *"nobody actively disliked it"* isn't good enough. What SO doesn't want is the people who can actually answer questions wasting their time and burning out on noddy garbage you could answer trivially yourself.

Comment: @MartinJames You are always so grumpy and negative D:

Comment: Has anyone claimed that  "StackOverflow is a great community for newbies"?   IIRC, it's aimed at 'professional and enthusiast programmers', not those who do not understand basic language syntax.  There is some level of expectation that the questions cannot be easily answered by a trivial Google or by reading the first chapter of 'Computers for Dummies'.

Comment: @Coder88: "*When some experienced programmers say "newbies ask dummy/bad questions, it's irritating" then I think they forgot they're once newbies too.*" No, we don't forget that. The difference is, when I had things to learn, I *learned them*. I didn't bother other people by asking them questions that were trivial to find on my own. I tried things *myself*. Sure, those were in the days before the Internet was widespread, so asking on forums was not possible for me. But what matters is the *attitude*; I would not have considered it courteous to ask questions that I could solve to myself.

Comment: @Coder88, if I find solutions for my most basic programming needs on this site, how on earth it is not "newbie friendly"?? Asking the same questions again and again, well that's not friendly from the newbies themselves... I believe one can learn an awful lot without asking a single question here, or not?

Comment: @brasilo:As a resource site where you can find infirmation SO is useful both for newbies and experts. But as a community site - where you can ask something to get answer - SO sucks for newbies. It's not newbie friendly. Anyway it's not aimed to newbies.  "Asking the same question again and again" one person doesn't ask the same questions again and again. Different persons ask same questions - not exactly same but similar questions. It's because of not knowing what they don't know, confusions etc.

Comment: @Coder88: "*"Asking the same question again and again" one person doesn't ask the same questions again and again.*" It doesn't matter if it's one person or 20. We're not here to help ***you***; we're here to help the person *after* you. If your question will only help *yourself*, then we don't want it here.

Comment: Not all questions marked as duplicate in SO is duplicate; at least not duplicate of the question it's claimed to be. E.g. this question is not same as the question at the link claimed to be duplicate. And it's not always easy to find the answer to a question at SO or at Google. I do research before askimg at SO, and when someone says "this is answered before" I become surprised. And I think answers to 95% of the upvoted questions at SO could be found outside SO if the person did enough research.

Comment: @Coder88 You're banned, complaining that you can't ask questions, and how to get out.  How...is it **not** a duplicate?  If giving constructive advice is verboten, since you seem to want the system to change, rather than you, then you're not going to get a very good reception here.  Thing is, SO's been around for *years*.  The system has it's flaws, granted, but it tends to work out.  In this case, I think the system is working *exactly* as it's supposed to.

Comment: @Coder88: "*I do research before askimg at SO*" I did a search for "is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file", and I got [this page in my first hit](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/). My second hit was [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035577), which is dated months before yours. The *only difference* between that one and yours is that you ask about a different program. Your claim that you do research does not square with the facts, nor is your claim that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I did ask some questions without enough research. But not all my questions are like that. I think you should learn to see differences too and not just focus on similarities. This question is not just about "how to get out of ban" but a question about a specific advice given on that question; about "edit your old questions". And more specificly it's about "what if my questions can't be edited because they are not "good" at all?" Yes it is related, but not just a duplicate.

Comment: Same comment just edited: When some experienced programmers say "newbies ask dummy/bad questions, it's irritating" then I think they forgot they're once newbies too. In almost all subjects, the newbies ask "dummy" questions almost all the time. I see it in the areas of my expertise. That's often the case. It's because newbies tend to be frustrated, confused and/or don't even know what they don't know. Thus the questions become "bad". You should study psychology too. But if you don't tolerate it, then don't claim "StackOverflow is a great community for newbies". It's clearly not true at all.

Comment: @Coder88 It has nothing to do with someone being new.  It has **everything** to do with users not reading the copious amounts of educational information put in front of them, and then getting mad when their question inevitably gets closed because they ignored it all.